# Announce when player enters the nether in 1.14?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm not very knowledgeable in mc commands but I had been trying to write a system that would announce if a player had entered the nether using execute and scoreboard, unfortunately the outcome was either it didn't work or it spammed chat, I eventually scrapped the whole thing out of frustration, is this even possible to do? If so what would you do?

Comment: Can you show some things you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can execute your command based on a dimension check like this:

```
/execute in the_nether run <command> @a[distance=0..,tag=!inNether]
```

And in a chain command block behind that, put this tag command so that the first command only gets executed once:

```
/execute in the_nether run tag @a[distance=0..,tag=!inNether] add inNether
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I tried using the first command to check the dimension, but it seems that `@a[distance=0..,tag=!inNether]` is included as part of the run which I assume it should not be, https://i.imgur.com/cJag7rC.png , I'm probably doing something wrong here but i'm to naive to know what.

Comment: Why do you enter something completely different than I wrote? Just copy-paste and write the command after `run` yourself, with the selector in the appropriate location.

Comment: Sorry I was messing around with the command because I couldn't get it to work initially, so what I should do is replace the <command>  https://i.imgur.com/zWmNWFx.png with any regular command right? e.g. `title`?

Comment: Yes, `<command>` is just any command you want to apply to those players.

Comment: Alright, I got that, so I tried replacing <command> with tellraw but I seem to have trouble with the selector https://i.imgur.com/tZLcmzL.png

Comment: You'll have to look at the wiki or a tutorial for command syntax, you can't just guess random parts and expect it to work. For example, what is that "@a" supposed to do?